# PHP Regex for filename

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, filenames

I made the user possible to change file names through a textarea, but now I'm having a regex problem.

As I see for Windows 7, these characters only are not allowed for filenames:

`\ / : * ? < > |`

But I stubbornly, perhaps also wisely, choose to minimize the regex to ONLY these special characters:

`- _ .`

All the others should have to be cut.

Can someone help me out with this regex?

preg_replace all but:
`A-Za-z0-9` and `- _ .`

I still really don't get the hang of it.

Comment: or a simple `str_replace();` to replace the unneded characters with an empty string like this `''`

Comment: `[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.]`. "anything that ISN'T one of the following..."

Comment: Have you tried anything? A google search for *regex filename* gives you plenty of useful results.

Comment: Marc's solution is what your looking for.

Comment: @IanOverton Althoguh it wouldn't quite work, as the '-' character would act as a range.

Comment: I believe you've missed `"`

Comment: Ofcourse... it just was simpeler than I though. Last time I asked some regex business they came up with the most 'random looking' special characters I've ever seen

Comment: Actually if you put the - at the end or escape it like he did you can use the - in the []

Comment: @IanOverton ah.. missed that it had been escaped. Personal preference is to always place it at the end [as I did in my answer :) ]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 _ .-]/', '', $filename);
```

The [] is a character class and the ^ negates it. So it literally matches anything other than the chars in that group.

Note that `-` is at the end, as it is a special range character if used elsewhere, e.g. 0-9

Comment: should it be \. ? Dot means any character.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has the character-set pretty-much laid out already. You'll just need to plug it into `preg_replace()` to get it going.

Try this:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]/', '', $filename);
```

The `^` at the beginning of the character set, surrounded by `[]`, states to *not*-match the list of characters. Therefore, the line can be read as "replace the characters that *are not* the following".