# Upload files to remote server using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, ftp

I’m a novice in php and html, and I found some codes that allowed me to upload files to a remote server using a html form and a php code.

I tested the code locally using wamp and I found some bugs, like I cannot overwrite an existing file and the formatting of the name of the file is not taken into consideration.

The files that I would like to upload are named in French and have spaces between them, the server is a debian server.
The goal of this code is to retrieve a URL.

The HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="remote_upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000000" />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

The PHP code:

```
$ftp_server = "192.168.1.111";
$ftp_user_name = "";
$ftp_user_pass = "";
$remote_dir = "C:\wamp\www";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

//default values
$file_url = "";

if($login_result) {
//set passive mode enabled
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];
$remote_file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];

$ret = ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);
while(FTP_MOREDATA == $ret) {
$ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
}

if($ret == FTP_FINISHED) {
echo "File '" . $remote_file . "' uploaded successfully.";
} else {
echo "Failed uploading file '" . $remote_file . "'.";
}
} else {
echo "Cannot connect to FTP server at " . $ftp_server;
}
```

Comment: Can't have spaces in the file names...

Comment: Is there a way to rename the file and display the new file name?

Comment: Yes.  Run a [preg_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13706148/870729) on the filename to remove spaces, etc., then use php *prior to uploading* to rename them (using [rename()](http://us3.php.net/rename)), then FTP that renamed file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i'm looking at exemples for doing it. I would like to ask you for overwriting files, what code can I add?

Comment: ftp overwrites by default.  Ensure you have the proper permissions on the ftp server.